# page only accesible to certain users PHP

Tags: php, session

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to allow acces to a webpage to certain users, but deny and redirect to the index page if not logged in as the right user.

Working with sessions in php

```
if ($SESSION["username"] == "... and ... " {
allow access
} else {
deny access
}
```

something like this?

Comment: better - assign roles to users and restrict pages by role, because if you'll restrict by username you'll have a LOT of conditions

Comment: Good practice is to allow access by user roles. instead of username. the method above using session is one of the method to check the access of a user. But using username is not recommended. Too much hard codings.

Comment: Add a role column in your db, and check if the session for user exist and user has role to access that page, means `Authentication and Authorization`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you want..

Add a field in the users table and assign roles in it. Such as user, admin etc...

When starting your session, set a session variable and assign the user a role (from the database of course...)

```
$_SESSION['role'] == "admin";
```

Finally, you can use something like this to check that -

```
if((isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == "admin")){
    header("location: admin.php");
}else{
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible

Example:

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_SESSION['admin'] && $_SESSION['admin'] != ""){
          Allow Access;
          header("location:admin.php");
     } else if(isset($_SESSION['user'] && $_SESSION['user'] != ""){
          Allow Access; 
          header("location:user.php");

     }
```

Comment: thank you for anwsering! but i've got nothing like an admin account, just names they login with. so for example only "bert", "jack" and "maus" can access the page how would i do that?

Comment: okay when they log in save their name in session and check that session on page header like this

if($_SESSION['name'] == "bert" || $_SESSION['name'] == "maus" || $_SESSION['name'] == "jack"){
      allow access;
}